# software that scans numbers on a website and outputs a notification when a threshold is reached

Tags: software-development, audio, ocr, screen-reader

I'm in search of a program or browser extension that can read specific numbers on a designated area of the screen. Once the numbers in that area reach or exceed a predetermined value, I'd like to receive a notification, preferably an audible alert. If anyone is aware of such a program, please inform me. About five years ago, I recall downloading a browser extension with similar functionality. It allowed me to choose a screen area with my mouse, set a threshold for the numbers in that area, and opt for either an audio alert or an automatic mouse click on a specified part of the screen. I hope I've effectively communicated my request. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, does it need to be for area? Or can it be manually set up with selector? Does it need to check for scrolling?

Comment: Im trying to read a dynamic number on a website.  So whatever gets the job done i'm happy with it.

Comment: Should edit the question in that case to specify that the selection is optional.